# issues about transparency when I using canvas(tkinter) to creating a polygon

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm using Canvas(from `tkinter import *`) to creating a polygon and want to set the polygon's **alpha** is 0.5, 
what should i do?

```
self.cv = Canvas(root, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg='green')
self.cv.create_polygon（0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, fill='gold'，tags = 'POLYGON'）
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do. The tkinter canvas doesn't support alpha channels.

Comment: oh, so which library can achieve this goal and the procedure, do you know?